# Loopback4: Switching between development and production environments

Tags: node.js, typescript, loopbackjs

Simply, how should I implement switching between dev and prod on a lp4 app.

I have my datasource added and everything works fine, but it's a .json file. How can I switch to another configuration saved in a .env file that could be read through dotenv package.

I have tried creating the datasource object manually, but I get errors so most likely my approach is wrong. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

*Hello from the LoopBack team*

LoopBack does not support dotenv out of the box.

If you want to keep your environment-specific configuration in files, then you should place your production configuration to `server/datasources.production.json` and then set the environment variable `NODE_ENV` to `production`. LoopBack is reading `server/datasources.${NODE_ENV}.json` at startup and applying any overrides from that file on top of the default configuration specified in `server/datasources.json`.

Having said that, we think it's better to use https://12factor.net and provide production configuration via environment variables. I guess that's what you are trying to achieve too?

Maybe you are looking for a way how to configure datasources from environment variables? LoopBack supports variable substitution in certain configuration files, `datasources.json` is amongst the supported ones. For example:

```
{
  "db": {
    "connector": "mysql",

    "database": "${MYSQL_DB}",
    "username": "${MYSQL_USER},
    "password": "${MYSQL_PASSWORD}"
}
```

When it comes to datasources in particular, we are recommending a slightly different approach:

- Connection settings used by local development are specified in `server/datasources.json` file using datasource configuration options like `host`, `database`, `username`, etc.
- When running in production (staging, etc.), the connection settings should be configured via a single connection string/url. The datasource file should contain an entry to set `url` property to the value provided by the environment.
- Under the hood, LoopBack and all connectors provide specific behavior to support this feature: the `url` property overrides all other settings, but is silently ignored when it's not present.

An example datasource configuration:

```
{
  "db": {
    "connector": "mysql",

    "database": "demo",
    "username": "demo",
    "password": "L00pBack"

    "url": "${MYSQL_URL}"
}
```

When running in production, you can set the connection string as follows:

```sh
export MYSQL_URL=mysql://prod:strong-password@localhost/realdb
```

Please refer to our older blog post https://strongloop.com/strongblog/managing-loopback-configurations-the-twelve-factor-way/ to learn more details.

Comment: The question was about dev/prod configuration for lb4. This answer seems to be a solution to lb3.